# What is the best collection to use in Java to store 100+ million hashed items

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, guava

Its 64-bit Java/Java15/Guava 30.1-jre.  I have tons of memory.  The data is 100M csv rows of:

```
parent, immediate parent,  ultimate parent
000ABC-X, 000ABD-X, 000ABE-X
```

Each value in the 2nd two columns can appear in the first one.
Given the parent, I either have to look up the immediate parent or the ultimate parent.

If I look up immediate parent, I'll also need to at a later point look up the ultimate parent.

Each character in the id is either a 0-9 or an A-Z.  The csv file itself is only 167Meg.
Each ID has a mapping to a whole other set of tens of millions of things and I need to verify and find missing relationships.

I.e. parent -> immediate parent -> ultimate parent
\                   \    (or)   /
other parent -> other ultimate/immediate parent

The immediate parent and the ultimate parent in other can map to either of the second two in the first.  The ids can be ordered.  There are no duplicates in the first column, though two different parents can have two different intermediate parents.

I prefer Guava collections and streaming operations and maybe parallelization.
https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/index.html

Rather than experimenting, I would appreciate any suggestions for efficient processing of the data or clever use of any of the collection classes to store the relationship and make it easy to compare to another similar collection to find missing relationships in the second set of 100M things.

I would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: The answer for 100M items isn't going to differ noticeably from the answer for 10 items.

Comment: Are the ids randomly distributed, or somewhat consecutive?  If they can be converted into integers where the highest minus the lowest is not too much greater than the total number of records, it will be faster to use an array than a map.

Comment: @Louis  So, like what?   1 parent->immediate parent HashMap and 1 parent->ultimate parent and then just use them both like regular HashMaps?  Between the two datasets, that give me four sets of tuples.  I can see that working, but was just curious if there is are any new types of collections that address these properties.

Comment: Actually in addition to the two hashmaps for each dataset, I do have one more hashmap that is a bijection from the one set to the other, so 5 hashmaps.   I wonder if there is a way to wrap all 5 into one structure (yeah, i know database, but I mean javaspace).

Comment: We don't know enough about how it is used and your constraints. How frequently is it processed? What is the access distribution (e.g. scans, zipfian)? What are the time constraints? Is it batch or latency sensitive? Why in-memory versus persisted & cached? Does the analysis require perfect accuracy or an estimate (e.g. see data sketches)? I could go on and on. Without constraints then the right answer is the simplest, which is most likely to bulk import into a SQL db due to being a well known and mature tool.

Comment: Why should there be “any new types of collections” when the “old types” do the job? And if there are things that could be done better, why should those improvements go into a new class, instead of improving the existing classes, like has been done for the last quarter century? The main memory consumption will be caused by the strings anyway, not by the hash maps referencing them.

Comment: @Holger, that's the question I'm seeking affirmation for.  Are the old collection types the best way.  Guava comes out with new collection types based on development patterns and theoretical computer science.  So the answer is, they DO improve existing classes with new implementations based on use case.  MY question is are there any that would benefit my use case.

Comment: @Ben Manes About less than 1% of one dataset changes per month. Think of new companies, acquisitions, mergers, IPOs, etc.  The second dataset is simply to take updated information and triple check for inconsistencies.  It'll be a batch process.  It's just to catch missing data relationships. There are errors in all the datasets, so cross-checking them is the only way to find things that don't add up.  The dataset is way too big for human review.  So yes, I do have the data in an SQL-based tool, but I need to write and experiment with the analysis algorithms in Java.

Comment: Guava's collections are mostly nice composites (e.g. Multimap), but not fancy new data structure algorithms. The cache, bloomfilter, and graph are the most complex cases. In your case, I would likely build ancillary db tables for faster analysis and delegate the work with well crafted queries. I would shy away from hand rolling it all in Java, but try to delegate to the db / stream engine / etc and give it the memory resources. If by hand, I would look at data sketches or other bit-wise friendly data structures for fast in-memory checks and fallback to slower db checks when not answered.

Comment: I found that Guava's ImmutableBiMap works for my middle mapping table so I can go back and forth easily between the two hashmaps of one type and the two of the other.  So, yeah, there seems to be really useful, new, friendly data structures.

Comment: I can't seem to edit my previous comment.  Apparently HashBimap allows for null keys and values which works for my semi-sparse dataset.  Immutable does not.  So there's a prima facie example of a new Guava collection type that takes into account usage.  The reason I wanted immutable is that I can get the index and go directly to the index of the opposing hashmaps with a guarantee it was the same items versus doing a search.  It was just a small optimization and simplification of the code.